# Онлайн интернет телевидение

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, javascript

Доброго времени суток!
Вот затеял сделать, что-то вроде телеканала в интернете!

Цель в том, чтобы можно было накидать роликов нон-стоп и они проигрывались и чтобы когда пользователь заходил на канал ролик проигрывался не сначала, а как на телевидении. Вот включили канал, а там уже середина фильма и Вы смотрите с того момента с которого Вы включили!

Но понятия не имею как это сделать.
Подскажите пожалуйста, что для этого нужно и как это сделать!
Хотелось бы даже напарника найти!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это называется [потоковая трансляция](http://habrahabr.ru/post/52190/). Напарником готов стать, и даже взять на себя всю техническую часть. Но только после озвучивания суммы, которая на это выделяется :) Не потому что жадный, а потому, что если нет денег хотя бы на VPS и канал, то и говорить не о чем.

Comment: спасибо.ок. дайте пожалуйста свой скайп или e-mail для связи заодно и подробности расскажу